# I am trying to sort chromosome aberrations by cytoband

Tags: r, sorting

I have the following data.frame "test":

```
Cytoband
9p 
1q
10p
22p
2q
```

I want to to get:

```
Cytoband
1q
2q
9p
10p
22p
```

Here is my code:

```
indices <- order(test$Cytoband, decreasing = FALSE)
test <- test[indices,]
```

But I get:

```
10p
1q
22p
2q
9p
```

Is there a simple modification? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also try using `mixedsort` or `mixedorder`

```
library(gtools)
out = data.frame(Cytoband = mixedsort(dat$Cytoband))

#> out
#  Cytoband
#1       1q
#2       2q
#3       9p
#4      10p
#5      22p
```

Using `mixedorder`

```
dat[mixedorder(as.character(dat$Cytoband)),]
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I also used the mixed order to extend it!

Answer (score 5):

```
x = c("9p","1q","10p","22p","2q")

y = x[order(as.numeric(gsub("\\D","",x)))]
y

[1] "1q"  "2q"  "9p"  "10p" "22p"
```

Comment: Johnathan in case it's not clear what's happening here, he uses `gsub` to extract only the numbers from the data, which can then be ordered numerically. It wasn't working for you because you were trying to order strings.

Comment: Dr. Mantis Tobaggan Thank you! Essentially, it takes all non-numeric characters, transforms them into null, then convert the remaining string into numeric.

Comment: Alexey Ferapontov Thank you for your input!

Answer (score 1):

```
test[order(as.numeric(gsub('(\\d+)[a-z]*', '\\1', test[,1]))),, drop=F]
  Cytoband
2       1q
5       2q
1       9p
3      10p
4      22p
```